# Summation of positive odd and even integers

Tags: integers

Find the sum of all odd and even divisors of 3600.
$6300=2^2.3^2.5^2.7$

The divisors are of the form $2^a.3^b.5^c.7^d$
Now sum of it's all divisors (odd and even) given by $(1+2+2^2)(1+3+3^2)(1+5+5^2)(1+7)$--------------(i)
Since $3,5,7$ are odd the value of a divisor be odd or even solely depends on power of $2$
The value of sum of odd integers are from (i) $(1)(1+3+3^2)(1+5+5^2)(1+7)$=$3224$ But it is WRONG
Also for summation of even integers from (i) $(2+2^2)(1+3+3^2)(1+5+5^2)(1+7)$=$19344$
It's also WRONG 
What am I doing wrong again and again?

The sum off odd divisors should be $403$ and of even integers should be $12090$

Comment: $(1.7)$ should be $(1+7)$. In any case, $7$ isn't a factor of $3600$.

Comment: That was writing mistake inspire of that it is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your prime factorisation of 3600 is wrong.*
It should rather be :
3600=2^4*3^2*5^2

Hence the sum of all odd divisors =(1)(1+3+3^2)(1+5+5^2)=403

The sum of all even divisors=(2+2^2+2^3+2^4)(1+3+3^2)(1+5+5^2)=12090

The sum of all divisors =(1+2+2^2+2^3+2^4)(1+3+3^2)(1+5+5^2)=12493=12090+403
=Sum of odd divisors +sum of even divisors

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For 6300 your answer is correct and for 3600 the sum of even is 12090 and odd is 403 .